# At work, see python programmer define an empty class inside of a class to get "dot structure". Is this bad?

Tags: python

I have seen this from a coworker, and want to know if this is legit. A class is defined in order to get the self.thing.morethings structure.

```
import numpy as np
class MyBigThing:
    def __init__(self):
        self.thing_builder()

    def compute(self):
        print(self.thing.morethings)

    def thing_builder(self):
        self.x = 2
        self.y = 2
        self.z1 = (2, 2)
        class thing:
            pass
        self.thing = thing
        self.thing.morethings = np.zeros(self.z1)
```

Personally, I would define an entirely separate class. I think the first implementation is meaningless, and will be better formed like this. Meaning we can construct more Things later down the line rather than create them adhoc in the MyBigThing.

```
import numpy as np
class MyBigThing:
    def __init__(self):
        self.thing_builder()

    def compute(self):
        print(self.thing.morethings)

    def thing_builder(self):
        self.x = 2
        self.y = 2
        self.z1 = (2, 2) 
        self.thing = Thing(self.z1)

class Thing:
    def __init__(self, shape):
        self.morethings = np.zeros(shape)
```

You can test either one with:

```
import test
x = test.MyBigThing()
x.compute()
```

You should get with either implementation:

```
[[0. 0.]
 [0. 0.]]
```

Comment: Are you certain the class object that `thing_builder()` defines isn't using *any* of the state of `mybigthing` or the `thing_builder()` method itself?

Comment: And `self.thing` doesn't exist in your example, only the local variable `thing`. You have probably removed too much context.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I added some more context.

Comment: The code you posted should use `self.thing_builder()`. The class definition, as posted, is indeed not useful and should be pulled out of the function. ***However***, if *any* of the class definition uses more context (such as the base class, or setting attributes from scoped-over variables) then there might be a reason to generate a new class object each time.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed that too. Sorry, wasn't being super diligent because I was more worried about the implications. thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a software development standpoint, doing such a thing is pretty non-standard and can lead to some confusion. I can imagine that there might be some benefit of grouping different variables inside common namespaces, however my spidey senses are telling me that this programmer is not following good development practices.

First of all, the `class thing` *only exists* inside of the function and not in `class mybigthing`, so right away we know that the code is invalid. What the programmer is intending to do is to have `self.thing` be the actual class `thing` and serve as some sort of namespace separator between variables, but the code you posted in fact is not even valid in Python:

```
class mybigthing:  
    def thing_builder(self):
        class thing:
            pass
        self.thing.morethings=1

a = mybigthing()
a.thing_builder()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in thing_builder
AttributeError: 'mybigthing' object has no attribute 'thing'
```

Okay, maybe you meant to do something like this:

```
class mybigthing:
    # code stuff
    class thing:
        pass

    # code stuff here
    def thing_builder(self):
        self.thing.morethings = 1

a = mybigthing()
a.thing_builder()
print(a.thing)
print(a.thing.morethings)
>>> <class '__main__.mybigthing.thing'>
>>> 1
```

That makes more sense. This is behaving as I expected. As to the question as whether this is valid: yes, this is valid Python, but this is *extremely bad* software development practice because the variable `morethings` is only instantiated within `mybigthing`, rather than `thing` like we would logically expect. This makes it unclear to programmers as to what `thing` is supposed to represent and what variables it is supposed to have. You first need to ask yourself, *why* are you creating a dummy class, and for what purpose do these variables need to be grouped in separate namespaces/classes?

Comment: I think even with the update, your conclusion holds. I was really confused when I got passed the code and asked to debug. It's just unclear what the Thing is supposed to do when it's empty imo. We are in research though, so good software engineering gets put on the backburner sometimes (so it seems).

Comment: Your updated code is still not valid Python, but I understand enough of what you mean. I am also in research so I understand the difficulty, however in my experience, antipatterns come more from general laziness or poor programming skills rather than time constraints.

Comment: Agreed. I updated the code and made sure everything was working.

Comment: I don't agree with the assessment that this is _extremely bad_ practice. See my answer for more details, but this idiom is in practice in a number of major open source projects like Django. While there is certainly an argument to be made about this idiom versus other composition approaches to solving the same problem, I think it's misleading to say in a blanket way that this is "extremely bad".

Comment: @MatthewStory We are talking about two different things I think. In your examples, your classes have some functional use... they do something. That seems practical and normal. OP's example is a class that literally does nothing (`pass`) and only serves partition variables into different namespaces. It makes the purpose of `thing` unclear and nebulous.

Comment: Yeah, since the final edit it's clear what the co-worker is doing is silly and bad.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern your co-worker is probably using is this one:

```
class Class:
    class AnotherClass:
        pass

    def __init__(self, **attrs):
        pass
```

Which is functionally equivalent to:

```
class AnotherClass:
    pass

class Class:
    AnotherClass = AnotherClass
```

While this isn't common practice, it is far from unprecedented or bad practice in Python and there are some major frameworks that use [this pattern](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/options/#model-meta-options), like Django which uses this pattern to define the `Meta` options class for a given model:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("author", "title"),)

    author = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

When used this way it's essentially a class that will only ever be used by `Book` via the `Meta` class attribute name. Defining this inline is an idiom which groups vital information about the behavior of the `Book` model withe the rest of the `Book` model definition, which makes the code more coherent.

I have used this idiom to define schemas for rest endpoints with marshmallow:

```
class API(Resource):
    class Schema(marshmallow.Schema):
        value = marshmallow.fields.String()

    def get(self):
        return self.Schema().dump({ "value": "yes" })
```

Neither of these examples makes use of this idiom as a way to namespace class definitions, which I would count as a very poor reason to use this idiom. If I encountered this in code review, I would want to verify that this class was only ever used by the class whose scope it was defined in, and that it implemented a contract expected by the parent class.